# Joint hypothesis test in R - restricted model of null hypothesis test that all coefficients are zero

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

I'm trying to perform a joint hypothesis test in r. For the following population regression model, $Grade_i = β_0 + β_1(Hours_i) + β_2(Male_i) + β_3(Econ_i) + β_4(SAT_i)+ μ_i$ , if I want to test the null hypothesis test that $β_1 = β_2 = β_3 = β_4 = 0$, how should I write my reduced model in R? Do I write $reducedModel <- lm(Grade ~ , data=ExportM4) $?

I know if I want to test for example, $β_2 = β_3 = β_4 = 0$, I can write $reducedModel <- lm(Grade $~$ Hours , data=ExportM4) $, but to test the null of $β_1 = β_2 = β_3 = β_4 = 0$, how should I write my code in R as restricted model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In R you do:

```
library(car)
#simulate some data
df = data.frame(
Grade=runif(100,min=1,max=100),
Hours = runif(100,min=1,max=100),
Male = sample(0:1,100,replace=TRUE),
Econ = runif(100,min=1,max=100),
SAT = runif(100,min=1,max=100))

f_full = lm(Grade ~ .,data=df)
coefs <- names(coef(f_full))
linearHypothesis(f_full, coefs[-1]) 

Linear hypothesis test

Hypothesis:
Hours = 0
Male = 0
Econ = 0
SAT = 0

Model 1: restricted model
Model 2: Grade ~ Hours + Male + Econ + SAT

  Res.Df   RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
1     99 85725                           
2     95 84512  4    1212.6 0.3408 0.8498
```

Which is also the equivalent of doing:

```
f_reduced = lm(Grade ~ 1,data=df)
anova(f_reduced,f_full,test="F")
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: Grade ~ 1
Model 2: Grade ~ Hours + Male + Econ + SAT
  Res.Df   RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
1     99 85725                           
2     95 84512  4    1212.6 0.3408 0.8498
```